# Why is wont my button pressed functions be declared to my attached interrupts?

Tags: class, arduino, syntax-error, arduino-uno

I am making a reaction game for my school project using Arduino and I want to use attach interrupt to register my button presses but the functions I have made won't be declared in the attach interrupt statement's I'm trying to make. This is my first-time using object-based programming Aswell, so I'm not entirely used to how it works.

```
#include <Arduino.h>
// Game class
/**
 * The Game class represents a reaction game that can be played between two players.
 * 
 * The game starts when any button is pressed. The RGB LED will turn red for a random
 * amount of time, and then turn green. The first player to press their button when the
 * RGB LED turns green will win the round. The winner's indicator LED and the RGB LED will
 * flash rapidly several times, and a fanfare will play from the buzzer. If a player presses
 * their button before the RGB LED turns green, they will lose the round and their indicator
 * LED and the RGB LED will flash rapidly several times, and a failure sound will play from
 * the buzzer. The class takes in the pin numbers for the buttons, LEDs, RGB LED, and buzzer
 * as parameters in the constructor. The class provides methods to start the game, blink the
 * winner LED, blink the RGB LED, and randomize the lights.
 */
class Game {
  private:
    bool started; // Whether the game has started
    bool over; // Whether the game is over
    int winner; // The winner of the game (1 or 2)
    int reactionTime; // The reaction time of the winner
    unsigned long startTime; // The start time of the game
    int button1Pin;
    int button2Pin;
    int led1Pin;
    int led2Pin;
    int redPin;
    int greenPin;
    int bluePin;
    int buzzerPin;
    int player1Score;
    int player2Score;
  public:
    Game(int b1, int b2, int l1, int l2, int r, int g, int b, int bz) {
      button1Pin = b1;
      button2Pin = b2;
      led1Pin = l1;
      led2Pin = l2;
      redPin = r;
      greenPin = g;
      bluePin = b;
      buzzerPin = bz;
      started = false;
      over = false;
      winner = 0;
      reactionTime = 0;
      player1Score = 0;
      player2Score = 0;
      pinMode(button1Pin, INPUT_PULLUP);
      pinMode(button2Pin, INPUT_PULLUP);
      pinMode(led1Pin, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(led2Pin, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(redPin, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(greenPin, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(bluePin, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(buzzerPin, OUTPUT);
      attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(button1Pin), button1Pressed, FALLING);
      attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(button2Pin), button2Pressed, FALLING);
    }
    void start() {
      Serial.println("Press any button to start the game");
      while (!digitalRead(button1Pin) && !digitalRead(button2Pin)) {
        // Wait for button press
      }
      started = true;
      Serial.println("Game started!");
    }
    void blinkWinnerLed() {
      if (over) {
        if (winner == 1) {
          digitalWrite(led1Pin, HIGH);
          delay(100);
          digitalWrite(led1Pin, LOW);
          digitalWrite(redPin, LOW);
          digitalWrite(greenPin, LOW);
          digitalWrite(bluePin, LOW);
          for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            digitalWrite(led1Pin, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(greenPin, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(bluePin, HIGH);
            delay(100);
            digitalWrite(led1Pin, LOW);
            digitalWrite(greenPin, LOW);
            digitalWrite(bluePin, LOW);
            delay(100);
          }
        } else if (winner == 2) {
          digitalWrite(led2Pin, HIGH);
          delay(100);
          digitalWrite(led2Pin, LOW);
          digitalWrite(redPin, LOW);
          digitalWrite(greenPin, LOW);
          digitalWrite(bluePin, LOW);
          for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            digitalWrite(led2Pin, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(greenPin, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(bluePin, HIGH);
            delay(100);
            digitalWrite(led2Pin, LOW);
            digitalWrite(greenPin, LOW);
            digitalWrite(bluePin, LOW);
            delay(100);
          }
        }
      }
    }
    void button1Pressed() {
      if (!over && started) {
        over = true;
        winner = 1;
        reactionTime = millis() - startTime;
        digitalWrite(led1Pin, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(redPin, LOW);
        digitalWrite(greenPin, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(bluePin, LOW);
        tone(buzzerPin, 440, 500);
        Serial.println("Player 1 wins!");
        Serial.print("Reaction time: ");
        Serial.print(reactionTime);
        Serial.println("ms");
        player1Score++;
        delay(2000);
        resetGame();
      }
    }
    void button2Pressed() {
      if (!over && started) {
        over = true;
        winner = 2;
        reactionTime = millis() - startTime;
        digitalWrite(led2Pin, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(redPin, LOW);
        digitalWrite(greenPin, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(bluePin, LOW);
        tone(buzzerPin, 440, 500);
        Serial.println("Player 2 wins!");
        Serial.print("Reaction time: ");
        Serial.print(reactionTime);
        Serial.println("ms");
        player2Score++;
        delay(2000);
        resetGame();
      }
    }
    void blinkRgbLed() {
      if (started && !over) {
        int randomTime = random(3000, 6000);
        digitalWrite(redPin, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(greenPin, LOW);
        digitalWrite(bluePin, LOW);
        delay(randomTime);
        digitalWrite(redPin, LOW);
        digitalWrite(greenPin, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(bluePin, LOW);
        startTime = millis();
      }
      if (over) {
        if (winner == 1) {
          digitalWrite(redPin, LOW);
          digitalWrite(greenPin, HIGH);
          digitalWrite(bluePin, LOW);
        } else if (winner == 2) {
          digitalWrite(redPin, LOW);
          digitalWrite(greenPin, HIGH);
          digitalWrite(bluePin, LOW);
        } else {
          digitalWrite(redPin, LOW);
          digitalWrite(greenPin, LOW);
          digitalWrite(bluePin, HIGH);
        }
      }
    }
    void resetGame() {
      digitalWrite(led1Pin, LOW);
      digitalWrite(led2Pin, LOW);
      digitalWrite(redPin, LOW);
      digitalWrite(greenPin, LOW);
      digitalWrite(bluePin, LOW);
      over = false;
      winner = 0;
      reactionTime = 0;
      startTime = 0;
    }
    int getPlayer1Score() {
      return player1Score;
    }
    int getPlayer2Score() {
      return player2Score;
    }
};

// Create a Game object with the specified pins
Game game(2, 3, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12);


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  randomSeed(analogRead(0));
  game.start();
  delay(250); // Add a 250ms delay after the game starts
}

void loop() {
  game.blinkWinnerLed();
  game.blinkRgbLed();
}
```

I've tried to move the functions around the code to make theme declared but wherever i put them they ether cause errors through my entire code. I'm pretty confident it's because the attach interrupts are in the class, but I don't know how to make it fit in with the rest of my code.

Comment: What do you mean by "won't be declared"?  Is there an error message?  If so then post it in your question.

Comment: add forward declarations or move the functions above setup(). it is a problem with Arduino builder. https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/73234/having-issue-with-a-redeclaration-as-a-different-kind-of-symbol/73238#73238

Answer (score 0):

You never clearly mention what exact error you are getting, but I would recommend to read [Calling Interrupt within a Class](http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=12983).

In addition to what Juraj mentioned about forward declaration. There are a few issues about your design of Class.

When an Arduino started, among all the things, it has a [main()](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/master/cores/arduino/main.cpp#L33-L51) function which do the system initialisation (such as defining the pins, setup the board variants, etc.) before passing the control to `setup()`. Your class construct is instantiated and trying to run code before the `init()` within the main() is called, and the Arduino does not know how to execute those code yet. This  is why almost all Arduino library has a `begin()` method, your class construct should only contains the class variable initialisation, no code should be run within the class construct until `setup()` is called. Re-design your class construct, move those codes such as setting `pinMode()` and interrupt to a `begin()` method, and call it in your `setup()`. Your current implementation might work depend on how compiler handling it, but there is no guaranteed.

Other references:

[Writing a Library for Arduino](https://docs.arduino.cc/learn/contributions/arduino-creating-library-guide)

[Arduino API style guide](https://docs.arduino.cc/learn/contributions/arduino-library-style-guide).

Your  interrupt handlers `button1Pressed()` and `button2Pressed()` is way to long, it should be kept as short as possible and should not contains blocking functions such as `delay()`, `tone()` and `Serial.print()`. I would suggest to read Nick Gammon's [Interrupt](https://www.gammon.com.au/interrupts).